# How to set a SQL statement into other statement to create a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to write a SQL statement that includes another statement, to get from that all a view. I have 1 data Table. this table have 3 rows(see: Table 1). What I'm trying to do is create a view which select all dates one time `DISTINCT`. now for every selected `date` row, select all rows where date = `date` and sum all `price`.

For example: the Main table

```
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+
| id | article_name | article_price |    date    |
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+
|  1 | T-Shirt      |            10 | 2020-11-16 |
|  2 | Shoes        |            25 | 2020-11-16 |
|  3 | Pullover     |            35 | 2020-11-17 |
|  4 | Pants        |            10 | 2020-11-18 |
+----+--------------+---------------+------------+
```

What im expecting is to have 3 rows(because the first 2 rows have the same date)

```
+------------+-----+
|    date    | sum |
+------------+-----+
| 2020-11-16 |  35 |
| 2020-11-17 |  35 |
| 2020-11-18 |  10 |
+------------+-----+
```

I'm having a hard time to think about an "Algorithm" to solve this.
any ideas?

Comment: Show us the statements you are trying to combine.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @DaleK That is the Problme, i cant catch the ideas to build a statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by`!

```
select date, sum(article_price) as sum_article_price
from mytable
group by date
```

Comment: nice man, that will do it except for one thing..... ive set the article_price to varchar to be able to insert value as `double data type`  like 13.99. any idea about what to do in this case?

Comment: Never use `varchar` for numbers - use `decimal`.